# access variable from every where in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I trying to `draw chart using google chart API`. This chart will get data from the database. The user can determine the date that he wants to draw the chart 
`weekly, year, Mysql monthly` ...etc.

when user choose week or month or year MySQL query can not access to this variable

the error says that the sql query is empty because can not access to the variable `$sql`

```html
session_start();
$data_set = $_SESSION['config'];
include("inc/users/$data_set.php");

include('database.php');
$connection = new database();
$con2 = $connection->connect($db, $user, $pass, $host);

$time = $_POST['tar'];

if ($time == 'week') {
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM `radacct` where date(AcctStartTime) = curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY  AND date(AcctStartTime) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY";
} else if ($time == 'month') {
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM radacct
    WHERE YEAR(AcctStartTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(AcctStartTime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
} else if ($time == 'year') {
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM radacct
    WHERE YEAR(AcctStartTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
}
$result = $con2->query($sql);

while ($result2 = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = array("c" => array("0" => array("v" => $result2['date1'], "f" => NULL), "1" => array("v" => (int) $result2['count'], "f" => NULL)));
}
echo $format = '{
    "cols":[
      {"label":"date1","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"label":"count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":' . json_encode($rows) . '}';
```

Comment: use brackets in if statemetns please :'( makes easier-to-read code

Comment: Your if blocks are probably falling though since you don't have a final `else` block to catch conditions that aren't met in your if/elseif blocks

Comment: And furthermore,post the exact error message in your question, not your vague interpretation of what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your else condition is missing. I add $time check condition but need to add else part.

```
 session_start();
    $data_set=$_SESSION['config'];
    include("inc/users/$data_set.php");
    include('database.php');
    $connection=new database();
    $con2=$connection->connect($db,$user,$pass,$host);
    $time= $_POST['tar'];

    if(!empty($time)){
        if($time=='week') {
            $sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM `radacct` where date(AcctStartTime) = curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY  AND date(AcctStartTime) < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY";
        } else if($time=='month') { 
            $sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM radacct WHERE YEAR(AcctStartTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(AcctStartTime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
        } else if($time=='year') {    
            $sql="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `username`) AS `count`,date(`AcctStartTime`) AS `date1` FROM radacct WHERE YEAR(AcctStartTime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";
        }
    } else {
        //you have to write default query here
        $result = $con2->query($sql);     
        while($result2= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[]=array("c"=>array("0"=>array("v"=>$result2['date1'],"f"=>NULL),"1"=>array("v"=>(int)$result2['count'],"f" =>NULL)));
    }

    echo $format = '{
    "cols":[
        {"label":"date1","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"label":"count","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows":'.json_encode($rows).'}';
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$sql` is empty, that means your `$time` is empty; have you tried to check what is the value ?
I think your  `$time=$_POST['tar'];` might be returning null from the form or at least not one of the case you tried.